# Implement Capacitive Sense (CSEN) peripheral in ZGM130S (z-wave module)

Tags: c, touch, z-wave

I want to develop a z-wave end node based ZGM130s SiP. Are there a example showing or document demonstrating how to implement The CSEN peripheral with z-wave 7.11.0 or z-wave 7.11.1 SDKs?

I include "em_csen.h" file in my project. In this file is noticed that for example code, include "em_csen_single.c" file but i can't find that file any where. Please help me where i can find that.

Comment: What is your project file structure? Could you try using the `find` command? What are you using to build your C code?

Comment: I am using simplicity IDE (offers by silicon labs). I add a sample project(switchOnOff example) and try to change it. Where should i use find command?

Comment: I am using z-wave 7.11.0 SDK and Z-Wave Plus V2 Application Framework  for developing, but there is not a complete document for it